# batch export excel workbook to 'prn' text-only format?

Tags: excel, batch-file, text, vbscript, export

i've written a script that i use to export excel workbooks to a '.prn'-style text-only format, one text file for each sheet in the workbook. the script is called from an external batch processor that runs periodically, using the windows 'cscript' script hosting command.

the script basically works fine, but it's very slow on larger workbooks. i was hoping someone could give me some pointers as to how i could make it run faster, or even provide an alternative method that works better.

the script is here : http://www.visualbasicscript.com/tm.aspx?high=&m=106086

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually exporting each value you could simply save the worksheets in the desired format:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename   = "..."
foldername = fso.GetParentFolderName(filename)

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
  prn = fso.BuildPath(foldername, ws.Name & ".prn")
  ws.SaveAs prn, 36
Next

wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Comment: actually, i spoke too soon. in fact, this solution works only with smaller worksheets, max 240 characters wide. many of the workbooks i need to export are at least twice this wide. [see, for example, ms comments here - http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;131554 -------- my original program will actually handle wider sheets, but... any ideas on how i can export this as text, conserving the formatting, but with better performance than my routine ?

Comment: @davidfurst If you need to create text files with such ridiculously long lines (for whatever reason) you'll probably have to do it the hard way.

Comment: 'ridiculously long lines'? ansgar, your comment is ridiculously unhelpful. i don't decide the format of the files, i just need to convert them. the reason is because there are users who need to process the data as text.